# In general, with Qt Creator, what can cause a program to run correctly when compiled in debug mode but to crash in release mode?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Can we make a list of causes that makes program to run correctly when compiled in debug mode but to crash in release mode, with Qt Creator. Let's talk in general, in most cases.

In my case, at point A, the program compiled and run correctly. After some work, at point B, it compiled but crashed at runtime in release mode and not in debug mode, I returned to point A by commenting my work between A and B, it has the same behaviour then point B, it compiles but crashes only in release mode. I think it is a mistake I did much before point A that was sleeping. It makes me not want to finish my program, since it's a free program I wanted to share in open source.

Comment: Undefined Behavior is a likely cause. Pay attention to all compiler warnings. if you did not get any warnings increase the warning level of your compiler and see if there are any after the increase.

Comment: Do you have any code examples? The current answer possibilities are way to broad (for me, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of undefined behavior can cause this type of issue. The most likely cause - writing past the boundary of an array/vector, or reading from there. It can be a destruction of an object that is already destroyed. Or a multithreading issue which reproduces only when execution is fast in release mode. It may be uninitialized struct, or a field of a POD type not assigned to in constructor.

In Debug mode the memory is allocated differently and in some cases may end up containing zeros (when passed to your program) rather than random garbage. This often causes crashes only in Release mode.

I strongly recommend you to setup "RelWithDebInfo" configuration to debug this issue, e.g. passing `-g` option to GCC when building in Release. Thus you will be able to stop in debugger when application crashes and identify the cause.

Otherwise your best bet is to do something like "binary search" over your code to find the exact location of the crash. Like, comment half the code, see if it still crashes, etc.

I know this explanation is a bit vague, but hope it helps!

Comment: _"I know this explanation is a bit vague ..."_ Well, what could be expected for a too vague and broad question?

Comment: "In Debug mode the memory is allocated differently and in some cases may end up containing zeros (when passed to your program) rather than random garbage." actually, typically it's the opposite; the debug heap fills deallocated pages with a fixed pattern to help spot uninitialized memory bugs.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I think you might as well be correct in general, I am just telling from my experience. Are there any prooflinks? :)